# pthread_t pointer as argument of pthread_create

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

The first argument of pthread_create is a pthread_t pointer. In the *hello program* below, if the first argument is a pointer to pthread_t (`pthread_t*`) instead of a pthread_t (`pthread_t`) the program ends with `Segmentation fault`...**why?**

I don't remember seeing `pthread_t*` as the declared type of the first argument of `pthread_create`. 
And chapter 2 of Butenhof's book *Programming with POSIX Threads* says:

> To create a thread, you must declare a variable of type `pthread_t` [not `pthread_t*`].

But [according to the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) the first argument of `pthread_create` is a pointer to `pthread_t`, so why the segmentation fault?

---

Segmentation fault

```
pthread_t* thr;
pthread_create(thr, NULL, &hello, NULL);
```

---

Runs OK

```
pthread_t thr;
pthread_t* pntr = &thr;
pthread_create(pntr, NULL, &hello, NULL);
```

---

hello program:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * 
hello(void *arg){
  printf("Hello\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int 
main(int argc, char **argv){
  pthread_t thr = 1;
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &hello, NULL);



  pthread_join(thr, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

---

pthread_create prototype:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);
```

Comment: See the difference between _defined_ and _declared_ in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pthread_t* thr;
pthread_create(thr, NULL, &hello, NULL);
```

declares a pointer to a `pthread_t` without allocating storage for it.  When you call `pthread_create`, it'll try writing to `*thr`.  This is at an undefined location and will almost certainly fail.

```
pthread_t thr;
pthread_t* pntr = &thr;
pthread_create(pntr, NULL, &hello, NULL);
```

works because you've declare storage (`thr` on the stack) for a `pthread_t`.

Note that the second, working, version can be simplified to what is used in your hello program

```
pthread_t thr;
pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &hello, NULL);
```

...which declares a `pthread_t` on the stack then passes a pointer to it into `pthread_create`.

Comment: Ohhh...
It is because `&` allocates space!
I couldn't spot such a silly thing.

Thanks

Comment: _Note that the second, working, version can be simplified to_ as is in the _hello program_.

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm afraid I hadn't read that far down the question.  I'll update my answer

Comment: `&` doesn't allocate space. `pthread_t thr;` declares the variable which means it allocates it on the stack. Then `&thr` takes the address of it.

Answer (score 4):

It is because if you simply declare a pointer, you can't expect it to point to allocated, initialised memory.

When you instead declare a `pthread_t` it gets allocated its own little block of memory that you can then get the address to with the `&` operator and pass it to `pthread_create`.

Comment: Right. Without `&` the pointer is not initialized. Thank you.

Comment: The `&` operator takes the address of the `pthread_t` as a pointer of type `pthread_t *` and this can then be used to call `pthread_create`. It doesn't initialise the pointer so much as simply create a valid pointer to an allocated area of memory.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. With initializing the pointer, I meant taking the address of (point to, i.e., assigning the address of `thr` to `pntr`) the memory where the pthread_t refers.

Note that: just between `pthread_t* pntr = &thr;` and the call to `pthread_create` `pntr` is pointing to UNallocated memory (because thr has not been initialized).

Comment: `pntr` is pointing to *allocated* memory because it points to `&thr`; `thr` could very well be *uninitialised*, though.

Comment: I see your point. Then `pntr` points to `&thr` which in turn points to unallocated memory... rigth?

Comment: `&thr` is the address of (pointer to the data of) `thr`, which is allocated memory on the stack (automatically allocated for you) created by the variable declaration `pthread_t thr;`. However, because you are merely declaring `thr`, it is not *initialised* which means that both `pntr` and `thr` are *allocated* but only `pntr` is initialised: It contains the value `&thr`. In the example that works, nothing is pointing to unallocated memory, which is exactly why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the followup.
With `thr`, _which is allocated memory on the stack (automatically allocated for you) created by the variable declaration_ `pthread_t thr` do you mean that the solely `pthread_t thr` allocates memory?

Before `pthread_create` what `thr` is pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some thread you can use below code:

```
pthread_t* thread_handles;
thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));
for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
{
  pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, threadFunc, (void*)input);
}
```

In this way you should allocate memory for your handles before calling `pthread_create`, just like when you want to create some "struct" you should first allocate memory for them.